# Chaquopy Build Failed: app:generateDebugPythonMiscAssets

Tags: python, android, android-studio, chaquopy

I am creating a kotlin-frontend/python-backend android app and want to use Chaquopy but I get the following error. Believe I followed the instructions on https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#development correctly but I keep on getting this error. Thank you very much.

```
:app:generateDebugPythonMiscAssets
Could not resolve com.chaquo.python:target:3.8.1-7
```

Can you please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Gradles (app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'com.chaquo.python'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.inprogress"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        sourceSets {
            main {
                python {
                    srcDirs = ["replacement/dir"]
                    srcDir "additional/dir"
                }
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}
```

Gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.61"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://chaquo.com/maven" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-alpha04'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.chaquo.python:gradle:7.0.3"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaquopy doesn't support pre-release versions of the Android Gradle plugin, and you should have received a warning about that.

Here's how to fix the problem:

- Change `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to the [stable Android Studio version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin)  (currently 3.6.3).
- Edit gradle-wrapper.properties to use the [corresponding Gradle version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) (currently 5.6.4).

When Chaquopy adds support for a new version of the Android Gradle plugin, it'll be announced in the [change log](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/changelog.html) and in [this summary table](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/versions.html).